# sort a csv file, add a field using bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a bunch of csv files that need "sorting". Specifically, there is a column 2 that I need to sort it, and add a new field in the first column contain some values according to one formula. What I wish to do, get the file result below starting from the `file_1`, Thanks in advance.

**file_1:**

```
2222,21,44444,55555  
2223,24,66666,33333  
2222,23,77777,99999
```

I wish sort `file_1` according to `field 2`, add a new column in the beginning of result_file (become 1st field) using this formula: `new field = 4000 - first field of file_1`, the output should be two files (result_file as below, and report_file report the missing records as below):

**result_file:**

```
1778,2222,21,44444,55555  
1778,2222,23,77777,99999  
1777,2223,24,66666,33333
```

**report_file**  according to field 3 of result_file:

```
**Error missing record 22 for the range 2222  
**Total records for the range 1778 is 2  
**Total records for the range 1777 is 1
```

In case no missing, we should get in the report just:

```
**No missing records  
**Total records for the range 1778 is 2  
**Total records for the range 1777 is 1
```

Thanks

Comment: @HR give a try to the proposed answer and provide a feedback

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is(are) situation(s) encountered during the generation of the **report_file** which is(are) not specified in the question and for which some arbitrary choice(s) was(were) made.

Maybe you should try to provide a **file_1** with 20 lines or more and the associated **report_file** example ?

Give a try to the awk script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
  FS=",";i
  OFS=",";
  sortedsize=0;
}
{
  newfields[$2]=4000-$1;
  lines[$2]=newfields[$2] ","  $0;
  count[newfields[$2]]++;
  if (sortedsize==0) {
    sorted[++sortedsize]=$2;
  } else {
    for (i=1;i<=sortedsize;i++) {
      if (sorted[i]>$2) {
        previous=sorted[i];
        sorted[i]=$2;
        for(j=i+1;j<=sortedsize;j++){
          print "1.2 " j;
          save=sorted[j];
          sorted[j]=previous;
          previous=save;
        }
        sorted[++sortedsize]=previous;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i>sortedsize) {
      sorted[++sortedsize]=$2;
    }
  }
}
END {
  missingrecords=false;
  for (i=1;i<=sortedsize;i++) {
    print lines[sorted[i]] > "result_file";
    if (i>1) {
      if (sorted[i] != (sorted[i-1] + 1) && newfields[sorted[i]] == newfields[sorted[i-1]]) {
        missingrecords=true;
        print "**Error missing record " (sorted[i-1] + 1) " for the range " newfields[sorted[i-1]] > "report_file";
      } else if (newfields[sorted[i]] != newfields[sorted[i-1]]) {
        if (!missingrecords) {
          print "**No missing records" > "report_file";
        }
        print "**Total records for the range " newfields[sorted[i-1]] " is " count[newfields[sorted[i-1]]] > "report_file";
        missingrecords=false;
      }
    }
  }
  i--;
  if (sorted[i] == (sorted[i-1] + 1) && newfields[sorted[i]] == newfields[sorted[i-1]] ) {
    if (!missingrecords) {
          print "**No missing records" > "report_file";
    }
    print "**Total records for the range " newfields[sorted[i]] " is " count[newfields[sorted[i]]] > "report_file";
  } else if (missingrecords) {
    print "**Total records for the range " newfields[sorted[i]] " is " count[newfields[sorted[i]]] > "report_file";
  } else if (newfields[sorted[i]] != newfields[sorted[i-1]]) {
    print "**No missing records" > "report_file";
    print "**Total records for the range " newfields[sorted[i]] " is " count[newfields[sorted[i]]] > "report_file";
  }
}
```

The test:

```
$ ls
file_1  script.awk
$ chmod +x script.awk
$ ./script.awk  file_1
$ ls
file_1  report_file  result_file  script.awk
```